# Transitioning to Lucee from older Railo versions

Tags: railo, lucee

It seems fairly straightforward to transition to Lucee from Railo 4.2, but we never made the jump and are still using Railo 3.3.4.

Is the process the same (replacement of jar files) or are there some additional issues to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't upgraded your stack yet, you'll probably want to. There are significant updates (including some high priority security updates) to Tomcat, the JRE, and of course Lucee since the original Railo 3.3 release.

It's a bigger job, of course, but staying up to date and secure is worth the effort. =)

-Jordan

Answer (score 0):

From Sean Corfield, via [Adam Cameron's blog](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2015/01/lucee.html):

> How smooth is the migration from Railo to Lucee? Let me quote Sean Corfield
>   here:
>
> "I was extremely impressed that migration was as simple
>   as dropping in the new JAR and it migrated all of my previous Railo
>   config! Awesome job on that."
>
> There is a entry on our wiki that explains it in detail, but it is
>   really simply a matter of replacing the railo.jar with the lucee.jar
>   and restart the engine. What happens is explained in the wiki entry
>   "Update from Railo".

Lucee provides [official "Migrate from Railo" documentation](https://bitbucket.org/lucee/lucee/wiki/Migrate_from_Railo).